# Highcharts dataLabels format

Tags: php, highcharts

I've a function which create a line chart. And I give it a boolean parameter to tell if I want decimal or not. Then i do :

```
if($decimal)
    $format = "{point.y:.2f}";
else
    $format = "{y}";
```

and in the creation of the chart :

```
    plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true, 
                    format: ".$format."
            }
     }
```

but it doesn't work. If instead of `".$format."` i put for example :`'{point.y:.2f}'` it works

I need to point out that ". ." is not the problem because i use it for some other options.

Where is my mistake please?

Comment: I assume that the problem is with that $format is string which, should be wrapped as php with <?php ?> tags. because in this way it is not parsed.

Comment: No because it's already in a php string =/

Answer (score 0):

I am going to guess that you need to wrap the value in quotes before including the variable.

So, this:

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true, 
                    format: ".$format."
            }
     }
```

becomes this:

```
plotOptions: {
            line: {
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true, 
                    format: '".$format."'
            }
     }
```

You should be getting some kind of javascript error though...are you?

Answer (score 0):

Take look how you can use it in php http://docs.highcharts.com/#preprocessing-data-from-a-database also in case when you use double quotes, you don't need to use points, so it should be "$format". Morever If you try to paste "{point.y:.2f}" as string,it will not work, because it is not a JSON. I advice to use formatter for define return function with prefix.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter